# Datatable charset ISO-8859-1 issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, character-encoding

I am using charset ISO-8859-1 encoding on my website and special char are correctly shown. The problem come when I use the plugin datatables. The table seems not recognising the special chars.

Is some charset setting to do on Javascript level?

At the moment the charset is set on server side, file config in Codeigniter:

```
$config['charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';
```

and also on library loading like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use UTF-8? It is compatible with ISO-8859-1 and capable of displaying most characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before returning de array run trought this, put it in a function or something

```
array_walk_recursive($response, function(&$item, $key){
  if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
    $item = utf8_encode($item);
  }
});
```